# Wordpress menu fix (css or javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a wp-woocommerce e-shop. I am using the same brand menu items in two places.
One of the brands' page: http://store.kapsula.com.ua/brand/insideu/

Screen-shot
https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/247272/ETt1GKo6yuTRkdHRyWOKHk92z8DaVDTh/

(in catalog brands list submenu is on the right under the cart icon)

When I select one of the brands both catalog and Brand main menu items are underlined. How can I with custom css or javascript make it so it underlines just the one main menu item

P.S. I am using ubermenu plugin, that allows to add custom class or ID to a specific menu item.

Comment: can you please show your code and add a jsfiddle to demo the problem. if you fix your web link the question wont help anyone else

Comment: Hey. I am using a plug-in that builds this menu, so I don't really have pure html/css code for this menu. But I can send you in private message ftp access.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, you need to remove underline from menu.
It is located in css

```
 mediaia="all"
.site-header .ubermenu.ubermenu-skin-none .ubermenu-item.ubermenu-item-        level-0>.ubermenu-target>.ubermenu-target-title:after {
display: block;
content: '';
height: 2px;
margin-top: 1px;
background: #222;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

just remove line

```
content:'';
```

And then add custom css to menu item that you want to be underlined.

```
![before](http://s15.postimg.org/zf4g3rg8b/before.jpg)
![after](http://s9.postimg.org/j64tfz6bz/after.jpg)
```

Comment: Hey. Sorry I didn't quite get what should I do. The problem is that I am using menu items that open the same pages in two places. As a catalog submenu called "brand list" and and main level menu item "brand list". So when I select from catalog sub-menu it underlines both catalog and brand main level menu items. What I need is if I select from catalog submenu only catalog to be underlined and if I select from brand list only brand menu item to be underlined.   https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/247753/AMNHDLQcWm2fGeqzfeBC34nyKAb5JFQe/

Comment: Hm..but when I open the page both items in menu are underlined. So you should first remove both underlines in css that I posted above. Then you should add js that selects one of this two item (depend which is pointed)

Am I right?

Comment: Yeap. I was trying to find that piece of code in css files but I couldn't.

Comment: Did you find it?
Why don't you add this lines to your style.css so you have no need to find that css line?

    media="all"
    .site-header .ubermenu.ubermenu-skin-none .ubermenu-      item.ubermenu-item-level-0>.ubermenu-target>.ubermenu-target-    title:after {
      display: block;
      content: inherit;
      height: 2px;
      margin-top: 1px;
      background: #222;
      visibility: hidden;
    }

Comment: I've added it to Custom CSS file, but it didn't help. Menu items are still underlined.

Comment: I edited my answer with 2 images. Check if we are talking about same thing. I removed 2 underlined menu items. Is that what you need. (we need to clear this up so we can proceed to 2nd step - add bottom border on hover).